# Why does Safari treat these table cells so differently than chrome and firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Here is some very simple HTML.  On Chrome (v57) and Firefox (v55) the two cells to the right are the same height, and on Safari (v11) they are not.  On Safari the top cell is only as big as needed for the content, and the bottom cell gets the rest of the space.

My question is - is one of these behaviours correct and one a bug?  Is there something simple I can do to get Safari to produce the same results as Chrome (like is there a browser styling difference at play here)?  I've inspected it and there are no user agent stylesheet differences that I can see.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.image-cell {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 bgcolor="#3faaed">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="image-cell">
      <img src="http://www.rizwanashraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/gorgeous-chrysanthemum-3d-wallpaper.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td>Top Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bottom Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know there are a limitless number of ways that I can produce a image with two equal sized boxes next to it - that isn't the question.  The question is, why the difference, and, can simple styling be added to homogenize them?  (This is a learning question, as I say, there are a million ways to display two boxes beside a box.  That's not what I'm asking.)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout seems to go out of its way to leave this unspecified, but I'm no spec expert.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that giving the cells the same height is a better solution than randomly assigning heights to them, so I would call the other browser's behaviour the norm and Safari's the deviation. But I'm not sure what your question is, really. You say you don't need to be told a way to produce a image with two equal sized boxes next to it, but you also ask if there is something simple you can do to get Safari to produce the same results as Chrome. So what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: PS IE11 also displays this snippet in a different way than Mozilla and Chrome, but at least the two cells are the same height...

Comment: @MrLister I expect an answer like, "The specs say X which applies to this in Y way" or, possibly, "Those browsers have X in their user agent stylesheet, which you missed, which causes this behaviour".  Some questions are about understanding what is going on rather than just getting the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#height-layout) leaves this explicitly undefined:

> CSS 2.2 does not specify how cells that span more than one row affect row height calculations except that the sum of the row heights involved must be great enough to encompass the cell spanning the rows.

This means in particular that CSS does not define how the height of a cell spanning more than one row is distributed across the rows that it spans.

There is no good way to homogenize the table's appearance except by providing absolute heights to the table and/or the table rows. Given an arbitrary image whose height is not known in advance, this is pretty much impossible with CSS table layout.

Comment: This may just expose my ignorance of the situation, but what I'm seeing is in HTML, not CSS, as I understand it.  Are you saying that the behaviour of layout for html elements like `<table>` is driven by the CSS spec even though it is a straight up HTML tag with no CSS?  If so, then your answer explains it and I'll accept it.  I just didn't realize that's how it worked.

Comment: @WillyC: Yes, HTML table rendering is governed by the CSS table model (at least, as of CSS2; no such model existed in CSS1).

Answer (score 0):

Table cells are rendered arbitrarily depending on their content, so you can never be sure how they are going to be rendered. Specifying dimensions is the way to get specific results.